# Display new window in second monitor, opencv

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, monitor

I have a opencv program in python that takes frames from a webcam and displays the feed.  When 'p' is pushed, it grabbes just the face and display this one frame in another window.

I would like to force this new window on to my **second** monitor while the camera feed is on the other one - the "main" monitor. Now it just displays on top of the feed.

I have been looking and searching but can't find anything else than moveWindow. How can I use this or another function to do this?

Hope someone can help me one this!

Comment: well you need to create a physical connection between monitors and send data from one to another, and this is out of opencv scope. if they share the same hardware, then try to enable multiscreen and force window locations (you need environment specific ui methods here, i dont even know if this is possible with opencv)

Comment: Okey, what if I use for example two raspberry pies to do this ?

Comment: Ok data transmission -serial or wireless- is what you need then; transfer the image data when the key is pressed

Answer (score 9):

I found that using named window followed by moveWindow allowed me to push the image to my second monitor. The -900 pushes the window upward.

```
def im_show(img, name, time):

     cv2.namedWindow(name)
     cv2.moveWindow(name, 900,-900)
     cv2.imshow(name, img)
     cv2.waitKey(time)

return
```